# Passing Laravel's controller data to a view

Tags: php, laravel

how do I pass in laravel data from controller to views without getting an undefined variable products?

Controller:

```
public function postSearch(Request $request){

    $text = $request->input('txtsearch');


$products = DB::table('products')->where('title', 'Like', $text)->get();


return redirect()->route('product.search', ['products' => $products]);

}
```

View:

```
@extends('Layout.master')

@section('content')

@foreach($products as $product)


{{$product->title}}



@endforeach

    @endsection
```

Comment: i dont see a variable of 'name' there?

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: the code seems right..but you might be in a wrong view

Comment: why are you not using view() helper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When redirecting, you should use `with()` to flash data into session:

```
return redirect()->route('product.search')->with(compact('products'));
```

And then get data from the session:

```
@foreach(session('products') as $product)
```

Comment: Is this secure to flash data into session though?

Comment: Yes, it's secure.

Comment: Can you explained why my code did not work in the first place? just curious.

Comment: @steven because you didn't pass any data. When you're using redirection you need to flash data to the session.

Answer (score 0):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data

> Redirecting to a new URL and flashing data to the session are usually done at the same time. Typically, this is done after successfully performing an action when you flash a success message to the session. For convenience, you may create a RedirectResponse instance and flash data to the session in a single, fluent method chain:
>
> ```
> return redirect('dashboard')->with('status', 'Profile updated!');
> ```
>
> After the user is redirected, you may display the flashed message from the session. For example, using Blade syntax:
>
> ```
> @if (session('status'))
>     <div class="alert alert-success">
>         {{ session('status') }}
>     </div>
> @endif
> ```

Answer (score 0):

In `@foreach` , you have to define the variable `$products` because in controller you define it as `['products' => $products]`

You have typo in your code, try this code instead :

```
@extends('Layout.master')

@section('content')

@foreach($products as $product)

    {{$product->title}}

@endforeach

@endsection
```

Hope that helps

Comment: No this does not work still getting undefined - products

Comment: are you sure you change it to `@foreach($products as $product)` ? your code was `@foreach($product as $products)` , make sure to change it, and make sure you call the right variable `{{$product->title}}`

Comment: your code seems good, I'm afraid it's just the typo in `@foreach` function

Comment: I have a solution using session. But thanks for your response.

Comment: I posted in the wrong code sorry it should have been $product as $product - which did not work from the beginning